# declarativeNetRequest not working except doc requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I am creating dynamic rules for declarativeNetRequest and passing the below data in `updateDynamicRules` api, I saw that these rules are only getting applied on doc type of request (refer image) and not on other requests, whereas this should work on all requests and apis.
[image]

```
{
    "addRules": [
        {
            "id": 67487208,
            "priority": 1,
            "action": {
                "type": "modifyHeaders",
                "requestHeaders": [
                    {
                        "header": "n",
                        "operation": "set",
                        "value": "true"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "condition": {
                "urlFilter": "|https*",
                "resourceTypes": [
                    "main_frame",
                    "sub_frame"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "removeRuleIds": [
        67487208
    ]
}
```

this is the Manifest file

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "description": "example",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "permissions": ["storage", "declarativeNetRequest"]
}
```

Comment: You explicitly limit the types to main_frame and sub_frame.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the addRules json array, in the conditions section, you limit your modifications to "main_frame" and "sub_frame" resource types, which is why only doc type requests are being modified. Adding all these resource types to the rule condition will solve your problem.

```
"condition": 
{ 
"resourceTypes": 
     ["csp_report", "font", "image", 
      "main_frame", "media", "object", 
      "other", "ping", "script", 
      "stylesheet", "sub_frame", 
      "webbundle", "websocket", 
      "webtransport", "xmlhttprequest"]
}
```

For more information on these types of resourceTypes, visit 
[ResourceTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/ResourceType)